# Objective C - attachments via MFMailComposeViewController not showing up

Tags: cocoa-touch, email, audio, wav, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to attach a wav-file from an iOS application but the attachment is not delivered even though it's visible in the composed mail.

Heres the related code:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:NSLocalizedString(@"mailTopic", nil)];
    [controller setMessageBody:NSLocalizedString(@"mailBody", nil) isHTML:YES];
    NSString *wavPath = [self exportAssetAsWaveFormat:self.myRec.soundFilePath]; // CAF->Wav export

    if (wavPath != nil) {
        NSLog(@"wavPath: %@", wavPath);
        NSData *recData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:wavPath];
        NSString *mime = [self giveMimeForPath:wavPath];
        [controller addAttachmentData:recData mimeType:mime fileName:@"MySound.wav"];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
    }
}


-(NSString *) giveMimeForPath:(NSString *)filePath {
    NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest* fileUrlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:fileUrl cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:.1];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:fileUrlRequest returningResponse:&response  error:nil];
    NSString* mimeType = [response MIMEType];
    NSLog(@"MIME: %@", mimeType);
    [fileUrlRequest release];

    return mimeType;
}
```

NSLog results:

NSLog(@"wavPath: %@", wavPath); -> "wavPath: /var/mobile/Applications/71256DCA-9007-4697-957E-AEAE827FD97F/Documents/MySound.wav"

NSLog(@"MIME: %@", mimeType); -> "MIME: audio/wav"

The file path seams to be ok (see NSLog data), and the mime type set to "audio/wav".. Cant figure this out..

Answer (score 2):

The error was that the wav-file was not 100% written by the time I create NSData out of it.. duuuh

Thanks for the effort guys

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the destination is stripping attachments of that type? Did you try manually sending a message with a .wav and see if it works? I had the same problem trying to send to Zendesk. Turns out they strip attachments for some mimetypes.

Comment: I've seen other apps being able to send wav.

Comment: Ok seems that this is the problem: NSData *recData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:wavPath];  when testing length of the data object it is always 0, but not nil..